# Remove webpack-dev-sever 1.14.1 and install 1.14.0

Tags: javascript, html, ubuntu

I want to know how to remove webpack-dev-server 1.14.1 and install 1.14.0 in Ubuntu in commands only.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null
at eval (eval at globalEval (jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2), <anonymous>:34:37)
at Function.each (jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2)
at Object.success (eval at globalEval (jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2), <anonymous>:21:10)
at j (jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2)
at x (jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4)
```

Is it okay to downgrade it?

Answer (score 0):

if you use `npm`:

`npm install webpack-dev-server@1.14.0`